# Finding a plane parallel to and equidistant from two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

So i have to write down the equation of a plane that is parallel to this two lines:

$$p1: y=2x-1 , z=3x+2 $$

$$p2: y=-x+1, z=4x-1$$

And the plane is at the same distance from both of those lines.

I was thinking i should that the dot product of normal vector and each of those lines direction vectors should equal 0, but i really don't know how to continue, beacause i get a not so simple equation and i still have two variables when i simplify it.
Also i don't how to use information that the planes is at the same distance away from line 1 as from line 2. I would really appreciate any help in solving this problem.

Comment: Will any plane satisfying those conditions do? You should find parameterizations of each line, which will tell you the directions of each line and a point on each line. Then find a line perpendicular to the direction vectors and the line connecting those two points. Then continue.

Comment: i did those but i don't know how to find a perpendicular line to the direction vector, and i don't how to advance from this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

Line $p_1$ is defined by $(1,2,3)x+(0,-1,2)$, while $p_2$ is defined by $(1,-1,4)x+(0,1,-1)$.

So the direction vector for $p1$ is $(1,2,3)$ and the direction vector for $p2$ is $(1,-1,4)$. A quick way to find a vector perpendicular to both of them is to calculate their [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product), [which is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation) $(11,-1,-3)$.

Therefore any plane that is perpendicular to the vector $(11,-1,-3)$ will be parallel to or coincident with your two given lines. The equation of such a plane is

$$11x-y-3z=c$$

for some constant $c$.

If the plane is equidistant from the two lines, then the value of $c$ will be equidistant from the values of that expression when a point on each line is substituted. The value of $11x-y-3z$ for point $(0,-1,2)$ on line $p_1$ is $-5$, while the value for point $(0,1,-1)$ on line $p_2$ is $2$.

Therefore we want $c$ to be the average of $-5$ and $2$, which is $-\frac 32$. Your desired plane is

$$11x-y-3z=-\frac 32$$

Answer (score 1):

Equation of p1 & p2 are :$$l1 : (0,-1,2)+t(1,2,3)$$$$l2 : (0,1,-1)+t(1,-1,4)$$
Notice that they don't intersect and thus we can find the required plane.
To find the direction $v : (v1,v2,v3)$ perpendicular to p1 & p2, solve 
 $(v1,v2,v3).(1,2,3)=0$ 
$(v1,v2,v3).(1,-1,4)=0$

solution : $t(-11,1,3)$ 

Now lets write the equation of our plane with the above normal : $$p:-11x+y+3z+d=0$$
To find $d$ equate distance of any point from l1 to p with any point from l2 to p :
Recall that the distance of the point$(x_0,y_0,z_0$) from the plane $ax+by+cz+d$ is given by $\frac{|ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} $

 so equating distance of $(0,-1,2)$ & $(0,1,-1)$ from p, we get
$$|5+d|=|-2+d|$$ $$d=-3/2$$
Thus our required plane is $$p:-11x+y+3z-3/2=0$$

Comment: may i ask about that part, how did u get that solution: t(-11,1,3) , that's the only think i didn't know how to get. other things are clear. thankyou for your answer.

Comment: since there are two equation and three unknown, you are going to get more than one solution. So pick any one of them to be free variable and calculate the other two. For example if I pick $v_2$ to be free then I can write $v_1=-11v_2$ and $v_3=3v_2$. So our solution is $(-11v_2,v_2,3v_2)=v2(-11,1,3)$.